# Python appending list

Tags: python, list, input

Trying to change a list so i can generate a password

```
passwordlength=int(input('Enter how long you would like the password')) # The user input 

for x in range(0,passwordlength):         
       password=''.join(characters)                
       print(password)
```

That is what i am working with now. Characters is what i am using for my list. This is giving me for the input the list repeated for the input number.

Every time i try and use a append to the list i just end up going backwards

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you explain what you expect `password` to be? eg - are you expecting a string of length `passwordlength` chosen randomnly from `characters` for instance?

Comment: what is in characters?

Comment: The list i have made is just a lot of numbers and letters , i am randomizing them every time.

Comment: Characters is a list of numbers and letters

Comment: you just keep assigning password to the joined elements of your list, what do you expect to happen? Maybe `password=''.join(characters[:passwordlength]) ` is what you want

Answer (score 2):

I think [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) may be what you want:

```
from random import sample

passwordlength = int(input('Enter how long you would like the password')) # The user input 


password = ''.join(sample(characters,passwordlength))
```

Or else take a slice up to `passwordlength`:

```
password = ''.join(characters[:passwordlength])
```

To validate the user input we can use a try/except and a while loop:

```
from random import sample

while True:
    try:
        password_length = int(input('Enter password length between 1-{}'.format(len(characters)))) # The user input
        if password_length > len(characters):
            print("Password is too long")
            continue
        password = ' '.join(sample(characters,password_length))
        break
    except ValueError:
         print("Please enter digits only")
```

If you have ints in your character list you will need to `map`  to `str` before joining.

```
password = ' '.join(map(str,sample(characters,password_length)))
```

Comment: I like the first suggestion better.

Comment: @Padraic should probably do a check or a try/except around the sample for where the input'd length > `len(characters)`... For the second, to handle that case, then you can cycle the input before the slice

Comment: @JonClements, True, keeping me honest as always ;)

Comment: @Padriac... umm... too much with one except... I'd put the length check and error and a `continue` and let the `ValueError` handle the `int` failure instead...

Comment: @JonClements, yep, I think that was more for my own amusement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some is a mock set up.  Where choice will randomly choice an item from a list

```
from random import choice

myaplha = #somelist of letters to choice from
password = int(input("Enter password length")):

passw = []
for i in range(password):
    passw.append(choice(myaplha))
print("".join(passw))
```

or

```
password = "".join([choice(myaplha) for i in range(int(input("Enter password length")))])
print(password)
```

Comment: Okay... the latest edit is a fair attempt, but you're missing a `.` after the `""`, and range doesn't a `str` etc...

Comment: And the OP appears to be using `print` functions and `int(input(...))` so you're missing a likely `int` to make sure `range` doesn't get a string

Comment: fixed, I assumed python2 which would cast a int string into an int if using input() instead of raw_input()

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
passwordlength=int(input('Enter how long you would like the password')) # The user input 
characters=['1','2','3','4','5','a','b','b']
password=[]
for x in range(0,passwordlength):         
       password.append(characters[x])                

print(''.join(password))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but this question isn't completely clear.

Here are the assumptions that I am making here:

- passwordlength is an integer containing the length to truncate to (which is in the code)
- characters is a list of characters / numbers that you want to use for the password.  e.g. characters = ['1', '2' ,'a' , 'c', 'd'] etc.

I don't understand what you are trying to do with the for loop?

I believe the following should do what you want.

password = ''.join(characters)[0:passwordlength]

Comment: Run the code and you'll see that either method i provide will give you a randomly generated password of length specified by the user.

Comment: The code in the original question does not generate a random password, At least not as written.

Comment: Fair enough, just supplying variation.